# regex separateb by | to take T:value for amazon tag

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

i have this string:

```
A:B0049P1VHS|T:the walking dead|popular
```

and i want to take only this paramenter in regex "the wallking dead" in regex

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex can work for you if the `|T:` is fixed

```
\|T:([^|]+)
```

`[^|]+` means any character except pipe `|` one or unlimited times.

Comment: ook and replace with..? example for the date i remember something like this: $1\$2\$3 and replace to $3. In this case $1|$2|$3 and replace with $2...sorry for the bad description XD... however, it's possibile?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but probably `.*\|T:([^|]+?).*` and replace with `$1` ??

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\|T:(.+?)\|
```

The first group will contain what you want.